# Did Docker compose with AWS ECS context stop working on September 1st 2021?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

On August 31st deploying to an AWS ECS context using Docker compose was working well, but as of September 1st and onward deploying terminates silently (nothing printed to the terminal) with error code 14.

Deployment has been done using the following Docker compose command, with active context set to an ECS context

```
docker compose --project-name redacted-project-name -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.aws.yml up
```

Is it a coincidence the issue started to appear when Docker applied changes to the Docker Desktop payment plans, or am I just being paranoid? A subscription to a Pro plan didn't solve the issue, but maybe a Team or Business plan is needed?

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if this is a regression of some sort. I have been playing with it these days and I noted that at some point it started behaving similar to how you are describing. For example, I do have a `docker-compose.yaml` file in my directory but it would just ignore it when I am in an ECS context:

```
➜  Downloads docker compose ps 
➜  Downloads docker compose up 
➜  Downloads
```

If I switched to the `default` context it starts complaining about a malformed entry:

```
➜  Downloads docker context use default
default
➜  Downloads docker compose up         
services.web Additional property port is not allowed
➜  Downloads
```

Once I fixed it and I switch back to the ECS context it just works.

```
➜  Downloads docker context use myecscontextvars
myecscontextvars
➜  Downloads docker compose up                  
[+] Running 10/10
 ⠿ downloads                 CreateComplete                                                                                                                                                                              141.5s
 ⠿ CloudMap                  CreateComplete                                                                                                                                                                               47.0s
 ⠿ WebTaskExecutionRole      CreateComplete                                                                                                                                                                               51.0s
 ⠿ Cluster                   CreateComplete                                                                                                                                                                                6.0s
 ⠿ LogGroup                  CreateComplete                                                                                                                                                                                2.0s
 ⠿ DefaultNetwork            CreateComplete                                                                                                                                                                                6.0s
 ⠿ DefaultNetworkIngress     CreateComplete                                                                                                                                                                                1.1s
 ⠿ WebServiceDiscoveryEntry  CreateComplete                                                                                                                                                                                3.0s
 ⠿ WebTaskDefinition         CreateComplete                                                                                                                                                                                3.0s
 ⠿ WebService                CreateComplete                                                                                                                                                                               76.4s
➜  Downloads docker compose ps 
NAME                                              SERVICE             STATUS              PORTS
task/downloads/655542088cb045789ff4af467ea88837   web                 Running             
➜  Downloads
```

This is weird cause I never noticed it failing silently like this. I will open an issue on the compose-cli repo to track it.

Update: [link to the issue on Docker GH](https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/issues/2068)

Answer (score 0):

Docker compose with an ECS context fails silently when it's passed a malformed yaml file.

Note that in this case malformed is specific to the ECS context -- your compose file will probably build just fine locally, but fail silently because of a feature that's not supported in ECS.

In my case, it was the `name` property causing it to fail.

One easy-ish way to debug it is to simplify test running `docker compose -f $filename config` against your yaml. Once it starts outputting data you'll know that it's no longer malformed.